# Error Plotting Dataframe - ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame whos structure is as follows:

```
    'data.frame':   78420 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ MATNR         : Factor w/ 354 levels "16I","16W","18P",..: 42 62 21 23 213 100 23 103 42 213 ...
 $ DERIV_DESC    : Factor w/ 277 levels "86 2.0 High AT",..: 150 174 138 144 112 192 144 195 150 112 ...
 $ SELL_DATE     : Date, format: "2015-02-11" "2015-01-06" "2015-02-09" "2015-01-02" ...
 $ OWNER_EMAIL   : chr  "pietdp@vodamail.co.za" "" "jonty.brown65@gmail.com" "tovic@gcs.co.za" ...
 $ CELL_NUM      : chr  "0825654797" "0828256975" "0829575014" "0825507622" ...
 $ GENDER        : chr  "Male" "Male" "Male" "Male" ...
 $ DATE_OF_BIRTH : Date, format: "1950-05-22" NA "1949-06-25" "1957-06-01" ...
 $ SERVICE_DATE  : Date, format: "2016-03-23" "2015-11-02" NA NA ...
 $ SELL_DLR      : int  12095 45070 63436 26400 63886 11500 26495 11054 23318 13048 ...
 $ RANGE         : Factor w/ 26 levels "86","Auris","Avanza",..: NA NA 18 NA 11 NA NA NA NA 11 ...
 $ TESTDRIVE_DATE: Date, format: NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Age           : int  66 NA 66 58 29 65 52 63 56 56 ...
```

I am trying to plot that data using `ggplot2` as follows.

```
    new_Data %>% group_by(GENDER,SELL_DATE) %>%
summarize(n=length(GENDER)) %>%
ggplot(mapping=aes(x=SELL_DATE, y=n, col=GENDER , size=n)) + 
  geom_point() +
ggtitle("Sales Figures per Gender") +
labs(x="Date",y="Sales")
```

I am getting the following error.

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'SELL_DATE' not found

I had this working before but when I increased the size of the dataset it stoped working.

Comment: please use `dput()`, output of `str()` can't be used to reproduce your code

Comment: HI There the data is confidential so cannot output whole dataset.

Comment: There are 471 Unique sell date entries is there a limit you can use to plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your data and it works absolutely fine for me:

```
new_Data = data_frame(
  GENDER = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 1000, replace = TRUE),
  SELL_DATE = sample(seq(as.Date('2016-01-01'), Sys.Date(), 1), 1000, replace = TRUE)
)

new_Data %>% 
  group_by(GENDER, SELL_DATE) %>%
  summarize(n = length(GENDER)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = SELL_DATE, y = n, col = GENDER , size = n)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Sales Figures per Gender") +
  labs(x = "Date",y = "Sales")
```

It might be a problem with your dataframe, in particualr the naming of the variables. 
It is difficult to help you further if you don't update your question with a more reproducible version of the problem and your data

Comment: I figured it out I had the plyr library loaded aswell which I think messed up my dplyr library. Thanks for the help!